# Error string-array android

Tags: android, android-studio

En el archivo de recursos de android tengo un `<string-array name="system">` con dos items, lo que deseo es llamarlo en una clase java que extiende de `RecyclerView.Adapter` para llenar un `string[]`, de la siguiente forma:

```
String [] arregloFiguras=Resources.getSystem().getStringArray(R.array.system);
```

Al ejecutar no arroja ningún error, pero la aplicación no despliega, una alerta indica que la app se encuentra dañada
¿Cómo puedo llenar un `string[] = {}` con valores de strings de la carpeta de recursos?
gracias.

Comment: podrias ampliar la información con algo de codigo? o imagenes de la alerta, todo lo que puedas aportar

Comment: Debes ser especifico y agregar el código o la información que describes. "alerta indica que la app se encuentra dañada ", escribe el mensaje tal y como se muestra, es recomendable agregar el mensaje del LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

No fui muy especifico, pero acá lo que necesitaba y como lo soluciones.
Este es el código del string-array que deseaba recuperar.

```
<string name="circulo">Circulo</string>
<string name="ovalo">Óvalo</string>
<string name="cuadrado">Cuadrado</string>
<string name="rectángulo">Rectángulo</string>
<string name="libre">Dibujo Libre</string>

    <string-array name="nombresFiguras">
    <item>@string/circulo</item>
    <item>@string/ovalo</item>
    <item>@string/cuadrado</item>
    <item>@string/rectángulo</item>
    <item>@string/libre</item>
</string-array>
```

y en la clase java debía haaer esto.

primero declarar.

```
String[] arregloFiguras;
String[] arreglo;
```

y en el constructor de la clase, que en este caso extiende de RecyclerView.Adapter

```
   public RecyclerAdapter(Context context)
```

{
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    arregloFiguras = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombresFiguras);
    arreglo = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombresDescripciones);
}

Answer (score -1):

`Resources.getSystem()` returna recursos del sistema, no de la aplicacion:

[Android docs:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

> `Resources.getSystem()` - Devuelve un objeto de recursos
>   compartidos global que **proporciona acceso solo a los recursos del
>   sistema (no recursos de la aplicación)** y no está configurado para la
>   pantalla actual (no puede usar unidades de dimensión, no cambia según
>   la orientación, etc.).

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que utilizar la instancia [`Resource` del `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?#getResources()):

```
String[] myArray = context.getStringArray(R.array.my_array)
```